# Counting the value for each status in a data set in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, geolocation, maps

From the variable:

```
var locations = [
    ['FULL',3.720185, 103.124075,1],
    ['EMPTY',3.719693, 103.123896,0],
    ['FULL',3.720916, 103.12492,1],
    ['EMPTY',3.721032, 103.124532,0],
    ['FULL',3.722299, 103.124587,1],
    ['FULL',3.723189, 103.124706,1],
    ['FULL',3.725067, 103.124593,1]
];
```

How do i get this result:

FULL = 5
EMPTY = 2

i need it for determining the waste management in my university based on the latitude and longitude

Answer (score 2):

considering all the sub-arrays within the `locations`  array are laid out as they are, you can simply use a `for loop` to check whether the first element of each sub-array has a value of `"FULL"` or `"EMPTY"`.

Example:

```js
var locations = [
    ['FULL',3.720185, 103.124075,1],
    ['EMPTY',3.719693, 103.123896,0],
    ['FULL',3.720916, 103.12492,1],
    ['EMPTY',3.721032, 103.124532,0],
    ['FULL',3.722299, 103.124587,1],
    ['FULL',3.723189, 103.124706,1],
    ['FULL',3.725067, 103.124593,1]
];

var full = 0;
var empty = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
   if(locations[i][0] == 'FULL') full++;
   if(locations[i][0] == 'EMPTY') empty++;
}

console.log("full " + full + "   empty " + empty );
```

Another solution if the `"EMPTY"` or `"FULL"` could be anywhere within the sub-arrays, i.e they are not guaranteed to be at index `0` all the time then you can use the solution below:

```js
var locations = [
    ['FULL',3.720185, 103.124075,1],
    ['EMPTY',3.719693, 103.123896,0],
    ['FULL',3.720916, 103.12492,1],
    ['EMPTY',3.721032, 103.124532,0],
    ['FULL',3.722299, 103.124587,1],
    ['FULL',3.723189, 103.124706,1],
    ['FULL',3.725067, 103.124593,1]
];

var full = 0;
var empty = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < locations[i].length; j++){
      if(locations[i][j] == 'FULL') full++;
      if(locations[i][j] == 'EMPTY') empty++;
  }
}

console.log("full " + full + "   empty " + empty );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, this is one of them:

```js
var locations = [
    ['FULL',3.720185, 103.124075,1],
    ['EMPTY',3.719693, 103.123896,0],
    ['FULL',3.720916, 103.12492,1],
    ['EMPTY',3.721032, 103.124532,0],
    ['FULL',3.722299, 103.124587,1],
    ['FULL',3.723189, 103.124706,1],
    ['FULL',3.725067, 103.124593,1]
];

res = {};
locations.forEach(item=>res.hasOwnProperty(item[0]) ? res[item[0]]++ : res[item[0]] = 1);
console.log(res);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k94qfa9r/2/

if you need it as a function:

```js
var locations = [
['FULL',3.720185, 103.124075,1],
['EMPTY',3.719693, 103.123896,0],
['FULL',3.720916, 103.12492,1],
['EMPTY',3.721032, 103.124532,0],
['FULL',3.722299, 103.124587,1],
['FULL',3.723189, 103.124706,1],
['FULL',3.725067, 103.124593,1]
];

function countItems(locs) {
  res = {};
  locs.forEach(item=>res.hasOwnProperty(item[0]) ? res[item[0]]++ : res[item[0]] = 1);
  return res;
} 
console.log(countItems(locations));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k94qfa9r/4/

If you need it as array:

```js
var locations = [
['FULL',3.720185, 103.124075,1],
['EMPTY',3.719693, 103.123896,0],
['FULL',3.720916, 103.12492,1],
['EMPTY',3.721032, 103.124532,0],
['FULL',3.722299, 103.124587,1],
['FULL',3.723189, 103.124706,1],
['FULL',3.725067, 103.124593,1]
];

function countItems(locs) {
  res = {};
  resArr = [];
  locs.forEach(item=>res.hasOwnProperty(item[0]) ? res[item[0]]++ : res[item[0]] = 1);
  for(var p in res)
   resArr.push([p, res[p]])
  return resArr;
} 
console.log(countItems(locations));
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k94qfa9r/6/